# Block import error: Backend error: Can't canonicalize missing block number #{BLOCK_NUMBER} when importing {BLOCK_HASH}

Tags: nodes

I'm trying syncing a new Khala node (based on `polkadot-v0.9.30` branch) from 0,
few hours later, I can see the output like this:

```
2022-11-01 07:08:54 [Parachain] Block import error: Backend error: Can't canonicalize missing block number #2482945 when importing 0xa0000aacfc918561284868cba29427613320594d3b129dc5981b0946f8368ead (#2487041)
2022-11-01 07:08:54 [Parachain]  Error importing block 0xa0000aacfc918561284868cba29427613320594d3b129dc5981b0946f8368ead: consensus error: Import failed: Backend error: Can't canonicalize missing block number #2482945 when importing 0xa0000aacfc918561284868cba29427613320594d3b129dc5981b0946f8368ead (#2487041)
2022-11-01 07:08:55 [Parachain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#2629792 (11 peers), best: #2482944 (0x7272…aac6), finalized #405357 (0x2ba4…5c69), ⬇ 1.8MiB/s ⬆ 2.7kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:08:56 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 48.7 bps, target=#15134037 (30 peers), best: #9247717 (0x6478…a2cc), finalized #9247232 (0xd3a2…417d), ⬇ 1.2MiB/s ⬆ 132.9kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:00 [Parachain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#2629792 (11 peers), best: #2482944 (0x7272…aac6), finalized #405357 (0x2ba4…5c69), ⬇ 8.8MiB/s ⬆ 3.3kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:01 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 43.5 bps, target=#15134037 (30 peers), best: #9247935 (0x9a21…f6fe), finalized #9247744 (0xc1c1…b50c), ⬇ 1.0MiB/s ⬆ 139.8kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:05 [Parachain] Block import error: Backend error: Can't canonicalize missing block number #2482945 when importing 0xa0000aacfc918561284868cba29427613320594d3b129dc5981b0946f8368ead (#2487041)
2022-11-01 07:09:05 [Parachain]  Error importing block 0xa0000aacfc918561284868cba29427613320594d3b129dc5981b0946f8368ead: consensus error: Import failed: Backend error: Can't canonicalize missing block number #2482945 when importing 0xa0000aacfc918561284868cba29427613320594d3b129dc5981b0946f8368ead (#2487041)
2022-11-01 07:09:05 [Parachain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#2629792 (11 peers), best: #2482944 (0x7272…aac6), finalized #405593 (0x89a5…6ff9), ⬇ 9.0MiB/s ⬆ 4.2kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:06 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 48.3 bps, target=#15134037 (30 peers), best: #9248177 (0xb440…3ff2), finalized #9247744 (0xc1c1…b50c), ⬇ 1.0MiB/s ⬆ 121.6kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:10 [Parachain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#2629792 (13 peers), best: #2482944 (0x7272…aac6), finalized #405593 (0x89a5…6ff9), ⬇ 9.7MiB/s ⬆ 4.6kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:11 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 42.5 bps, target=#15134037 (30 peers), best: #9248390 (0xdbc3…aad9), finalized #9248256 (0xb48f…6a96), ⬇ 953.1kiB/s ⬆ 120.9kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:15 [Parachain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#2629793 (11 peers), best: #2482944 (0x7272…aac6), finalized #405593 (0x89a5…6ff9), ⬇ 9.0MiB/s ⬆ 4.2kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:15 [Parachain] Block import error: Backend error: Can't canonicalize missing block number #2482945 when importing 0xa0000aacfc918561284868cba29427613320594d3b129dc5981b0946f8368ead (#2487041)
2022-11-01 07:09:15 [Parachain]  Error importing block 0xa0000aacfc918561284868cba29427613320594d3b129dc5981b0946f8368ead: consensus error: Import failed: Backend error: Can't canonicalize missing block number #2482945 when importing 0xa0000aacfc918561284868cba29427613320594d3b129dc5981b0946f8368ead (#2487041)
2022-11-01 07:09:16 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 47.7 bps, target=#15134045 (30 peers), best: #9248629 (0x0da6…9e37), finalized #9248256 (0xb48f…6a96), ⬇ 1.0MiB/s ⬆ 130.5kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:20 [Parachain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#2629793 (13 peers), best: #2482944 (0x7272…aac6), finalized #405829 (0x92bb…2cd7), ⬇ 5.7MiB/s ⬆ 7.7kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:21 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 43.3 bps, target=#15134046 (30 peers), best: #9248846 (0x4dff…ab5b), finalized #9248769 (0xeb85…0f4a), ⬇ 956.7kiB/s ⬆ 123.9kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:25 [Parachain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#2629795 (13 peers), best: #2482944 (0x7272…aac6), finalized #405829 (0x92bb…2cd7), ⬇ 6.9MiB/s ⬆ 5.7kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:26 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 43.1 bps, target=#15134046 (30 peers), best: #9249062 (0xf167…12a9), finalized #9248769 (0xeb85…0f4a), ⬇ 889.9kiB/s ⬆ 140.6kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:30 [Parachain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#2629798 (14 peers), best: #2482944 (0x7272…aac6), finalized #406070 (0x49b1…c151), ⬇ 9.4MiB/s ⬆ 5.5kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:31 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 45.6 bps, target=#15134046 (30 peers), best: #9249290 (0x88d5…5cf9), finalized #9249281 (0x2c85…36a1), ⬇ 1.1MiB/s ⬆ 146.0kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:35 [Parachain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#2629798 (15 peers), best: #2482944 (0x7272…aac6), finalized #406070 (0x49b1…c151), ⬇ 5.8MiB/s ⬆ 3.6kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:36 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 45.9 bps, target=#15134046 (30 peers), best: #9249520 (0x9522…56f7), finalized #9249281 (0x2c85…36a1), ⬇ 1000.6kiB/s ⬆ 112.3kiB/s
2022-11-01 07:09:38 [Parachain] Block import error: Backend error: Can't canonicalize missing block number #2482945 when importing 0xa0000aacfc918561284868cba29427613320594d3b129dc5981b0946f8368ead (#2487041)
2022-11-01 07:09:38 [Parachain]  Error importing block 0xa0000aacfc918561284868cba29427613320594d3b129dc5981b0946f8368ead: consensus error: Import failed: Backend error: Can't canonicalize missing block number #2482945 when importing 0xa0000aacfc918561284868cba29427613320594d3b129dc5981b0946f8368ead (#2487041)
2022-11-01 07:09:38 [Parachain]  Error importing block 0x27939286e6722c962d6c964e4bfc4a3371b2ac6d78f6b2ee534a6a1ad7543786: block has an unknown parent
```

The parachain syncing seems stuck for hours, and no sign to continue.

Comment: Facing with the same issue, sometimes happen, sometimes not.
Current workaround is wiping parachain db, but would like to find out why this happens in the first place.